# How do you protect a resource on a webserver using REST API

Tags: authentication, rest

I wanted to know how to can i protect a resource on a webserver using REST API.Like for example i want to access http://www.xyz.com/folder/impresource.doc but before accessing that i have to be authenticated. The thing is i am try to create a simple mobile client to authenticate with a rest service and then be able to access the resource.

I would appreciate a good example explaining how it can be done Thanks  :)

It would be nice if i could get an example in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implement a web service (be it REST, or be it SOAP) in some programming language (for example, Java or C#) running in some "container" (for example, IIS/.Net or Tomcat).

The layer *below* REST (for example, the C# code you're using to implement your IIS/.Net/SOAP web service, or the Java code in your .war) is the layer where you want to write any custom access code.

Alternatively, some vendors (for example, Amazon S3) have already done this for you:

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

Other vendors (such as Microsoft) give you a way to use *their* authentication infrastructure with your web service:

[Secure REST Service Microsoft Azure AppFabric](http://dotnetninja.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/securing-wcf-rest-service-with-azure-appfabric-access-control-service-and-oauth/)

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use a servlet filter, which will send an error code if it does not find an authentication object in the user session and if authenticated let the request handling proceed. A very popular implementation of this approach is Spring security[http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html]